# Getting Battery Capacity on HP Pavilion: psutil returns None on battery power

Tags: python, hp-pavilion

I have  HP Pavilion X360 laptop which runs:
Ubuntu 18.04
Python 2.7 and 3.7

```
import psutil
```

if on AC power

```
>>> psutil.sensors_battery()
sbattery(percent=79.77341807129041, secsleft=-2, power_plugged=True)
```

if on battery power

```
>>> psutil.sensors_battery()
#returns None
```

return 'None'

On a Mac Book Pro 2017 (High Sierra), it works fine.

It seems to be a hardware problem with HP Pavilion X360. Any thought how to fix it or diagnose it further?